# How can I associate names from first column with repeating rows?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have say this dataframe:

```
gene0   1   2   3
gene1   0   0   5
gene2   6   8   0
gene3   5   5   5
        0   0   5
        1   2   3
```

and I would like to associate numbers from "unnamed" columns with genes to have the following:

```
gene0   1   2   3
gene1   0   0   5
gene2   6   8   0
gene3   5   5   5
gene1   0   0   5
gene0   1   2   3
```

What is the best way to do it? Do I need to use linux or R for that?

Comment: Hi Mark, does the unnamed column have some logic to it? If you want to add names to an already named df it is better to supply a vector with all the rownames in order, if it is something like if col1 + col2 > x = geneY we can talk about it further

Comment: Thank you, Bruno. The only logic to give names to rows is based on "previous" values, like here for ex. ```0   0   5``` is associated with ```gene1``` and ```1   2   3``` is ```gene0```

Comment: You should really add `dput` to your question to make it easy for others to understand how your data actually is. It is not clear to me whether the first column is rownames or actual column. Also do you have blanks or `NA` in them.

Comment: Correct, first column is rownames. What do you mean by "add ```dput```"? Sorry I don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `match` from `base R`

```
a1 <- do.call(paste, df1[-1])    
df1$V1 <-  df1$V1[match(a1, unique(a1))]
df1$V1
#[1] "gene0" "gene1" "gene2" "gene3" "gene1" "gene0"
```

#### Update

Using the OP's dataset

```
df1 <- read.csv("newest.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df1$id[df1$id == ""] <- NA
a1 <- do.call(paste, df1[-1])    
df1$id <-  df1$id[match(a1, unique(a1))]
length(unique(df1$id))
#[1] 621    

head(df1$id, 20)
#[1] "pop13_110" "pop1_2"    "pop16_108" "pop2_10"   "pop2_2"    "pop2_3"    "pop2_4"    "pop2_5"    "pop2_6"    "pop2_7"    "pop2_8"   
#[12] "pop2_9"    "pop2_10"   "pop2_11"   "pop7_81"   "pop2_13"   "pop2_15"   "pop2_15"   "pop2_16"   "pop22_20" 
tail(df1$id, 20)
# [1] "pop22_2"   "pop22_3"   "pop22_4"   "pop22_5"   "pop22_8"   "pop22_9"   "pop13_60"  "pop16_131" "pop23_11"  "pop22_25"  "pop22"    
#[12] "pop22_14"  "pop22_15"  "pop22_32"  "pop22_28"  "pop16_56"  "pop22_18"  "pop9_9"    "pop22_21"  "pop22_22"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = c("gene0", "gene1", "gene2", "gene3", NA, 
NA), V2 = c(1L, 0L, 6L, 5L, 0L, 1L), V3 = c(2L, 0L, 8L, 5L, 0L, 
2L), V4 = c(3L, 5L, 0L, 5L, 5L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Thank you akrun. Your solution is the most understandable for me and even the first part seems to be enough (I just need a list of rownames that match its values, so I can just paste it into my Excel file), however when I save my ```df1$V1``` into a .csv file and compare it with the original (that in real has 647 rows) in Excel, it matches only till 13th row and then nothing is matched...

Comment: @Mark May be you have a data strucuture different than the one I showed

Comment: maybe...the original is just an .csv excel file

Comment: @Mark  After you read the data from excel in R, can you check the `df1 <- read_excel('fiie.xlsx'); str(df1)`

Comment: it's ```'data.frame': 1171 obs. of 17 variables: $id: Factor w/647 levels``` and all other columns are ```int```

Comment: Can you change it to `character` i.e. `df1$id <- as.character(df1$id)` and then do the match

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204433/discussion-between-mark-and-akrun).

Comment: @Mark Updated the post

Answer (score 2):

One `dplyr` and `tidyr` option could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by_at(-1) %>%
 fill(V1)

  V1       V2    V3    V4
  <chr> <int> <int> <int>
1 gene0     1     2     3
2 gene1     0     0     5
3 gene2     6     8     0
4 gene3     5     5     5
5 gene1     0     0     5
6 gene0     1     2     3
```

Or:

```
df %>%
 group_by(group = group_indices(., !!!select(., -1))) %>%
 fill(V1) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 select(-group)
```

Sample data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "gene0   1   2   3
gene1   0   0   5
                 gene2   6   8   0
                 gene3   5   5   5
                 NA 0   0   5
                 NA 1   2   3",
                 header = FALSE,
                 na.strings = "NA",
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Oh that is nice, I avoid  rownames like the plague, but it is cool that you can group by them at index -1

Comment: Thank you, but I am sorry I don't understand the code ... I have a ```Error in select(., -1) : unused argument (-1)``` And what is Sample data? Can you explain please? Thanks!

Comment: I am trying the first option ```df %>%
 group_by_at(-1) %>%
 fill(V1)``` but it does not fill anything. I have just ```" "``` instead of wo names...

Comment: Sample data is the assumed structure of your data. If it is different, then please post it using `dput()`. For the rest, try to update to the newest version of `dplyr` and `tidyr`.

Answer (score 0):

The naive solution

library(tidyverse)

```
df <- tribble(~col1,~col2,~col3,
                     1,2,3,
                     0,0,5,
                     6,8,0,
                     5,5,5,
                     0,0,5,
                     1,2,3,
                     1,1,1)

df %>% 
  mutate(gene = case_when(col1 == 1 & col2 == 2 &col3 == 3 ~  "gene0",
                          col1 == 0 & col2 == 0 &col3 == 5 ~  "gene1",
                          col1 == 6 & col2 == 8 &col3 == 0 ~  "gene2",
                          col1 == 5 & col2 == 5 &col3 == 5 ~  "gene3",
                          TRUE ~ "unkown_gene"))
```

Another much more extensible option is to create a tabble with gene definitions(can even be imported from excel or something)

```
df1 <- tribble(~gene,~col1,~col2,~col3,
              'gene0',1,2,3,
              'gene1',0,0,5,
              'gene2',6,8,0,
              'gene3',5,5,5)
```

and simply join the new observation on it

```
df %>% 
  left_join(df1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution with `base R` in addition to the solution by [@akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59376463/12158757), where `match()` is used over rows that cross from columns from `V2` to `V4`

```
df$V1[which(is.na(df$V1))] <- df$V1[match(data.frame(t(subset(df,is.na(df$V1))[-1])),
                                          data.frame(t(subset(df,is.na(df$V1))[-1])))]
```

such that

```
> df
     V1 V2 V3 V4
1 gene0  1  2  3
2 gene1  0  0  5
3 gene2  6  8  0
4 gene3  5  5  5
5 gene0  0  0  5
6 gene1  1  2  3
```